# Soundcloud JS API connect method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

I'm trying to make client side application to get tracks from soundcloud according to [docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication)
I've added `<script src='http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js'></script>` to `<head>` of my site. And added following code as docs says to my js.

```
//I've replaced YOUR_CLIENT_ID with my client id I got when registered my app and http://example.com/callback with my callback.html also I've filled redirect uri field with it.
    SC.initialize({
      client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      redirect_uri: 'http://example.com/callback'
    });
    
    // initiate auth popup
    SC.connect(function() {
      SC.get('/me', function(me) {
        alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
      });
    });
```

Also I've created callback.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
    <b style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I get popup window where I can enter my email and password and when I enter it, I got message: This popup should automatically close in a few seconds. But it's not closing. In console I got message:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://sscopin.temp.swtest.ru" from accessing a frame with origin "swappedout://".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "swappedout". Protocols must match
```

Also I don't see any alert, so I suppose that it's not connected.Also `console.log` of SC shows me SC object.
Solutions? Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In Soundcloud's sample callback.html, the code:

```
<body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

must be altered to:

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

This allows the popup to close properly and completes the login flow if the application settings are correctly configured to the same domain (localhost or production, but not a mix of the two).

Answer (score 1):

The error itself is mentioning the solution. Make sure both, redirect url and the web page that causes that pop up, have the same URL pattern including the protocol like  `http://`

E.g:

URL that causes pop up for login : http://www.example.com/soundcloud.php

Callback URL : http://www.example.com/callback.php

If you forget to write `http` or `www` then window.opener object will not work and can not identify child window.

Answer (score 0):

Read more docs.
[Here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript) I've found, that it's not necessary to use rederict_uri at all. Only client_id.
Also [here](http://code.runnable.com/Uub0h3RTaFUTAAEy/get-a-users-tracklist-on-soundcloud-in-javascript) I've found how to get tracks uploaded by people.
So, it's quite simple.
To play tracks from user we should:
1. Initialize object with our client_id obtained after registration of application.

```
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: 'my_client_id'
    });
```

2. To get track id we should:

   ```
   SC.get('/users/Username/tracks', {limit: 100}, function(tracks){
           console.log(tracks);
   });
   ```

Username is in settings>profile>profile url of soundcloud. Tracks is an list of objects where there is an id property that we can use next
 3. To add playing of track on click

```
$('#loadTracks').live('click', function(){
    SC.stream('/tracks/track_id', function(sound){
        sound.play();
    });
});
```